# What is a proper way to express derivatives with respect to a symbol?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax

Mathematica's default way of representing derivatives is to express them with respect to a function's input slot. But what if I want to use the chain rule? To replace df(x)/dx with df(0.5 y)/dy 0.5, where x=2y. What is the Mathematica way of doing this? Is the proper way using  [esc] pd [esc] [Ctrl][-][x]?

I'm following a quantum mechanics lecture and trying to write down the math on the slides to Mathematica. I just can't figure out how to express the steps in Mathematica code. I'm really struggling with the first slide of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DDvnybFrVlE&index=21&list=PLoRUNeJAicqZ_qLKTrdbXvvg_WTtFK_Ds

Apparently, the first step in solving a differential equation is often a change of variables, which he proceeds to do on the first slide. He uses the chain rule to change the variable that psi is differentiated with respect to.

Comment: `D[f[y/2], y]`?  It's not clear to me what code you're starting with and how you want to transform it. Well, that's what I'm assuming you want to do.

Comment: There's also `f'[x] /. f -> (f[#/2] &)`, but it keeps `x` instead of substituting `y`.

Comment: Or are you merely asking how to input [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) via a shortcut, which is described in the first bullet point under "Details and Options" section of the docs for [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html)?

Answer (score 0):

WL provides two basic ways to produce derivations: derivatives of functions w.r.t. slots (uinsg `Derivative`), and derivatives of expressions with respect to variables (using `D`).  The shorthand you mention is for `D`, so just use it with an expression you are interested in, and the chain rule will be applied automatically. E.g.,

```
In[]:= Clear[f, g]; D[g[f[x]], x] /. {x -> x0}

Out[]= Derivative[1][f][x0] Derivative[1][g][f[x0]]
```

(where the space is implicit times).